# OpenXml get page number to which each paragraph in a .docx file

Tags: openxml-sdk

I have a Word docx file and I want to retrieve all the paragraphs in OpenXml with c#.
I need to know:
1.-The number of pages of the Documents.
2.-The page number to which each paragraph belongs.

Can you show an example where the paragraphs of the document are read?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, As [Why only some page numbers stored in XML of docx file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48680399/why-only-some-page-numbers-stored-in-xml-of-docx-file) answers, docx dose not contains reliable page number service. Xml files carry no page number, until microsoft Word open it and render dynamically. Even you read openxml documents like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.pagenumber?view=openxml-2.8.1 .

You can unzip some docx files, and search "page" or "pg". Then you will know it. I do this on different kinds of docx files in my situation. All tell me the same truth. Glad if this helps.

---

Few month ago, I reprogramed a python package call docx2python to do similar thing. I reproduced a structured(with level) xml format file from a docx file. As far as I know, a paragraph contains several Runs and each Run contain one only text. You can read this document to see how to do it. Plain paragraphes are not hard to read.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.paragraph?view=openxml-2.8.1 . Glad if this helps.